# display array in a label in swift

Tags: swift, object, parse-platform

I would like two display Object data gotten from Parse in swift. I have tried using label in this way but it only displays the last element in the object. Please how can I make it display all the element in the object in the label. Like one element to one label. Thanks

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "Questionnaire")
 query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {

     // There were no errors in the fetch
        if let returnedObjects = objects {
     // var text = ""
     // Objects Array is not nil
     // loop through the array to get each object

             for object in returnedObjects {
                 print(object["question"] as! String)
                 // text.append(object["question"] as! String)
                self.Label.text = (object["question"] as! String)


             }


        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: you can use tableview for display multiple labels

Answer (score 2):

You can do **in one line** like that and      join all `question` with `,` separator ,  you can change separator to any `(empty, -,...etc)`

```
if let returnedObjects = returnedObjects {
    self.Label.text = returnedObjects.map {($0["question"] as? String) ?? nil}.compactMap({$0}).joined(separator: ",")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tableview for this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! YouTableViewCell 
        cell.textLabel.text = yourArray[indexpath.row] as? String ?? ""          
        return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's important to use `UILabel`

```
var concatenatedString = ""

for object in returnedObjects {

    concatenatedString += object["question"] as! String
}

self.Label.text = concatenatedString
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the array and setting each value to `Label.text`. However, setting `Label.text` will replace what was on the label before. That's why you only see the last item.

One solution is to display the string representation of the array:

```
self.Label.text = "\(object)"
```

Another solution is to display the items in a table view Suganya Marlin has suggested. You would need to conform to `UITableViewDatasource` and implement the various methods. Here is a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).