# How to list Firebase Dictionary into UILabel Swift

Tags: swift, list, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, uilabel

I´m working on a Pizza order app. I'm trying to load order into UILabel as list. Orders database is Firebase and the app is swift coded. When I print the value of array  I can see all items. But items list can not be loaded into UILabel. Just load the child by autoID on top, ignoring any others.
Really thanks for your help, this my first app on swift and firebase and maybe this is a silly question :(

[**This is the Firebase childs by autoID. Only the one on the top can be loaded**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD9o6.png)

**If I prints values works perfectly, but UILabel only displays last item.**

```
func observePreOrder() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let preOrderRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/profile/\(uid)/pedidos/100_PRE-ORDER/")

    preOrderRef.observe( .value, with: {snapshot in

        if let Pedido = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            let keys = Pedido.allKeys
            for key in keys {

                if let nextDict = Pedido[key] as? [String: Any] {

                    let Pizza = nextDict["PIZZA"] as? String ?? ""
                    let Ingredientes = nextDict["INGREDIENTES"] as? String ?? ""
                    let separator = " \n"
                    let array : [String?] = ["·Producto: \(Pizza)", nil, "·Ingredientes: \(Ingredientes)"]
                    let PedidoSTR = array.compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: separator)


                    self.testLabel.text = PedidoSTR// only display last item from Firebase
                    print(PedidoSTR)// Display ALL items from Firebase 
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.testLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
                    self.testLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
                    print(self.testLabel.text as Any)



                }

            }

        } else {
            print("NANAIN")
        }
    })

}
```

**This is the output value**

·Producto: Pepsi Cola Lata 
·Ingredientes: 
·Producto: Mitad Ali oli‍ y Mitad Boloñesa‍ Pequeña. 
·Ingredientes: Mitad con + Base de Tomate + Mozzarella + Salsa Ali Oli + Pimiento Frito + Jamón Serrano + Crema De Módena y Mitad con + Base de Tomate + Mozzarella + Salsa Boloñesa + Ternera + cebolla + Extra De Queso

Comment: Hi, did you set delegate and datasource of collection view?

Comment: Can I add the rest of the code where you call `loadOrdersMethod()` and where you specify collectionview number of items?

Comment: Now I’m trying just display orders on UILabel, so there’s no collection view

Comment: Finally I found a solution on this post:
[display array in a label in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286664/8675029)

Comment: **Finally I found a solution in this post** [Display arrays on UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286664/8675029)

Answer (score 0):

**I have a little more located the problem**

```
    func observePreOrder() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let preOrderRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/profile/\(uid)/pedidos/100_PRE-ORDER/")

    preOrderRef.observe( .value, with: {snapshot in

        if let Pedido = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary { // "\(Pedido)"load all items on UILabel

            let keys = Pedido.allKeys // "\(keys)"load all keys on UILabel
            for key in keys {  // "\(key)"load only last key on UILabel but all keys on print output

                if let nextDict = Pedido[key] as? [String: Any] { // "\(nextDict)"Load only last item on UILabel but all items on print output

                    let Pizza = nextDict["PIZZA"] as? String ?? ""
                    let Ingredientes = nextDict["INGREDIENTES"] as? String ?? ""
                    let separator = " \n"
                    let array : [String?] = ["·Producto: \(Pizza)", nil, "·Ingredientes: \(Ingredientes)"]
                    let PedidoSTR = array.compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: separator)


                    self.testLabel.text = "\(nextDict)"
                    self.orderTitle = self.testLabel.text

                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                    self.testLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
                    self.testLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
                    print(self.testLabel.text as Any)
                    print(array.count as Int)



                }

            }

        } else {
            print("NANAIN")
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Finally I found a solution on this post. I just add an variable with empty array in order to display array loops as single string map.